# jQuery to PHP submit and post not returning any results

Tags: php, jquery

I have looked at similar questions, but still cannot get my code to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My html page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="output"></h1>
    <form id="form">
      <input type="text" id="input">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#form").submit(function(){

      let input = $('#input').val();

      $.post('new.php', {value : input, function(data){
        $("#output").html(data)}
      })
    })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My PHP page looks like this:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['value'])){
  $value = $_POST['value'];
  echo $value;
};
?>
```

Comment: Need to prevent the default form submit or page will simply reload

Comment: Is jQuery correctly loaded? Try `console.log($.fn.jquery);` in the [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your script to prevent the default HTML form submit event from reloading the page.
You can use `preventDefault()` like in the example below or simply return false.

```
$("#form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let input = $('#input').val();

    $.post('new.php', {value : input, function(data){
         $("#output").html(data)}
    })
 })
```

**UPDATE**

Curly braces misplaced too.

```
$.post('new.php', {value : input}, function(data){
    $("#output").html(data)
})
```

Thanks to Louys Patrice Bessette

Comment: Thank you for answering, I changed the script but it is still not working.

Comment: If you use Chrome, Firefox or Opera (these I'm familiar with), inspect the page and switch to Console tab. Check if there is any error printed, if none, switch to Network tab, resubmit the form and see if the request was actually sent.

Comment: Oh okay, I got a 404 on my jQuery file. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Make sure the `src` of the jQuery script you added to the head is pointing to the correct URL

Comment: I fixed the 404 and checked the network tab and it looks like the requests are going through

Comment: Curly bracket misplaced! It should be: `$.post('new.php', {value : input}, function(data){$("#output").html(data)})` --- Where `{value : input}` is an object.

Comment: Still no luck, maybe a problem with my server? I am using Ampps on local host

Comment: my code now is:$("#form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    let input = $('#input').val();

    $.post('new.php', {value : input}, function(data){
         $("#output").html(data)})
    })

Comment: Try to chain that error handling code: `.fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(error);
    });` and look at the console.

Comment: Thank you for all your help everyone! I think I will bring it in to my computer science teacher so that he can see the whole situation and see if he can help with it.

Comment: Got it to work! My IDE had not saved the changes, it was the curly braces that were the problem

Comment: Lol, it happens to the best of us. Glad it's finally working.